# Where to find successful proposals of previous ERC calls?

Tags: funding, europe

I plan to apply for ERC ADVANCED GRANT 2015. Is there any place for finding previous winner proposals?

The templates are straightforward, but it is very useful to see what winners have written in their proposals, particularly in the Scientific Proposal (Part B2).

Comment: the problem is that winners normally do not wish to share their secret weapons.

Answer (score 10):

Currently, most people don't share their research proposals, whether successful *or* unsuccessful in their bid for funding.

However, this may soon change in the near future as it has been noted that more transparency would be extremely beneficial for a variety of reasons [1,2].

That said, there's a nice list of [publicly available grant proposals in the biological sciences here](http://jabberwocky.weecology.org/2012/08/10/a-list-of-publicly-available-grant-proposals-in-the-biological-sciences/). None are specifically for the ERC ADVANCED GRANT 2015 though. [Figshare](http://figshare.com/) is also a good place to check for public research proposals.

*UPDATE* - There is now also a dedicated website for openly available grant proposals: [ogrants.org](https://www.ogrants.org/) it is a [Moore Foundation funded initiative](https://www.moore.org/grant-detail?grantId=GBMF4563). One of the grants listed at that site is a European Research Commission Starting Grant (Strategic Predictions for Quantum Field Theories by John Joseph M. Carrasco).

**Further Reading**

1. Mietchen D (2014) The Transformative Nature of Transparency in Research Funding. PLoS Biol 12(12): e1002027. doi: [10.1371/journal.pbio.1002027](http://journals.plos.org/plosbiology/article?id=10.1371/journal.pbio.1002027)
2. Gurwitz D, Milanesi E, Koenig T (2014) Grant Application Review: The Case of Transparency. PLoS Biol 12(12): e1002010. doi: [10.1371/journal.pbio.1002010](http://journals.plos.org/plosbiology/article?id=info:doi/10.1371/journal.pbio.1002010)